# Counting characters, words, length of the words and total length in a sentence

Tags: shell, wc

I have to write a script that takes a sentence and prints the word count, character count (excluding the spaces), length of each word and the length. I know that there exist `wc -m` to counter number of characters in the word, but how to make use of it in script?

```
#!/bin/bash

mystring="one two three test five"
maxlen=0;
for token in $mystring; do
  echo -n "$token: ";
  echo -n $token | wc -m;
    if [ ${#token} -gt $maxlen ]; then 
      maxlen=${#token}; fi;
done

echo "--------------------------";
echo -n "Total words: ";
echo "$mystring" | wc -w;
echo -n "Total chars: ";
echo "$mystring" | wc -m;
echo -n "Max length: "; 
echo $maxlen
```

Comment: Sounds like [tag:homework].  If it is, please tag it as such. For many of us, if we see that tag, we'll make a greater effort to help you learn why the answer is what it is, rather than just providing a solution.

Comment: thank you, ghoti, will mention further. But i am just practising with scripts and shell commands

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: The one liner for the CLI: `echo 'Here is my test String' | wc -m`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

riffing on Jaypal Singh's answer:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ mystring="one two three four five"
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ echo "string length: ${#mystring}"
string length: 23
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ echo -n "lengths of words: "; i=0; for token in $mystring; do echo -n "${#token} "; i=$((i+1)); done; echo; echo "word count: $i"
lengths of words: 3 3 5 4 4 
word count: 5
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ echo -n "maximum string length: "; maxlen=0; for token in $mystring; do if [ ${#token} -gt $maxlen ]; then maxlen=${#token}; fi; done; echo $maxlen
maximum string length: 5
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i output only maximum length?

Comment: what do you mean by "maximum length"?

Comment: like token "three" is the largest word in the string, and it's length is 5

Comment: Sorry buddy out for dinner but looks like you are all set! ;) Good luck!!

Answer (score 10):

```
echo $mystring | wc -w
```

or

```
echo $mystring | wc --words
```

will do a word count for you.

You can pipe each word to wc:

```
echo $token | wc -m
```

to store the result in a variable:

```
mycount=`echo $token | wc -m`
echo $mycount
```

to add to the total as you go word by word, do math with this syntax:

```
total=0
#start of your loop
total=$((total+mycount))
#end of your loop
echo $total
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

mystring="one two three test five"
for token in $mystring; do
  echo -n "$token: ";
  echo -n $token | wc -m;
done
echo "--------------------------";
echo -n "Total words: ";
echo "$mystring" | wc -w;
echo -n "Total chars: ";
echo "$mystring" | wc -m;
```

Comment: Wow, cool, thanks!) how can i check maximum length of the word in whole string?

Answer (score 4):

```
string="i am a string"

n=$(echo $string | wc -w )

echo $n

4
```

The value of n can be used as an integer in expressions

```
eg.

echo $((n+1))
5
```

Comment: would you please make this as one-liner too

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. In bash you can use `#` to get the length of your variable.

Also, if you want to use `bash` interpreter use `bash` instead of `sh` and the first line goes like this -

`#!/bin/bash`

Use this script -

```
#!/bin/bash

mystring="one two three test five"
for token in $mystring
do
    if [ $token = "one" ]
    then
        echo ${#token}
    elif [ $token = "two" ]
    then
        echo ${#token}
    elif [ $token = "three" ]
    then
        echo ${#token}
    elif [ $token = "test" ]
    then
        echo ${#token}
    elif [ $token = "five" ]
    then
        echo ${#token}
    fi
done
```

Comment: There are a couple ways to do arithmetic in the shell. I like `foo=$((bar + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

The `wc` command is a good bet.

```
$ echo "one two three four five" | wc
       1       5      24
```

where the result is number of lines, words and characters.  In a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

mystring="one two three four five"

read lines words chars <<< `wc <<< $mystring`

echo "lines: $lines"
echo "words: $words"
echo "chars: $chars"

echo -n "word lengths:"
declare -i nonspace=0
declare -i longest=0
for word in $mystring; do
  echo -n " ${#word}"
  nonspace+=${#word}"
  if [[ ${#word} -gt $longest ]]; then
    longest=${#word}
  fi
done
echo ""
echo "nonspace chars: $nonspace"
echo "longest word: $longest chars"
```

The `declare` built-in casts a variable as an integer here, so that `+=` will add rather than append.

```
$ ./doit
lines: 1
words: 5
chars: 24
word lengths: 3 3 5 4 4
nonspace chars: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
var=(one two three)
length=${#var[@]}
echo $length
```

**output**

```
3
```

Comment: A brief explanation would improve this answer.

Comment: I'll soon explain it. First I need to remove my appendix (seriously).