# How can I count the number of characters in a Bash variable

Tags: linux, bash

How can I count all characters in a bash variable? For instance, if I had

```
"stackoverflow"
```

the result should be

```
"13"
```

Comment: One option is [`wc`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_wc.htm).

Comment: **using wc and tr together**


`echo stackoverflow|tr -d '\n' | wc -c`

Comment: Take `function char-count() { echo -n "$1" | wc -c | awk '{print $1}' }`, save it in your .zshrc and use it: `char-count "hello world"` and you get **11** since `${#VAR}` is not working on macOS UNIX zsh.

Comment: @Aiias Broken link. linux.about.com redirects to www.lifewire.com

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Using the `${#VAR}` syntax will calculate the number of characters in a variable.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Link could die.

`${#parameter}` gives the length in characters of the expanded value of parameter is substituted. If parameter is `*` or `@`, the value substituted is the number of positional parameters. If parameter is an array name subscripted by `*` or `@`, the value substituted is the number of elements in the array. If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by a negative number, that number is interpreted as relative to one greater than the maximum index of parameter, so negative indices count back from the end of the array, and an index of -1 references the last element.

Comment: Bash doesn't properly count unicode characters or other multibyte characters.

Answer (score 94):

Use the [wc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) utility with the *print the byte counts* (`-c`) option:

```
$ SO="stackoverflow"
$ echo -n "$SO" | wc -c
    13
```

You'll have to use the *do not output the trailing newline* (`-n`) option for `echo`. Otherwise, the newline character will also be counted.

Comment: You don't need echo. If going for `wc` do `wc -c <<< $SO`

Comment: @jacwah: this will also count the trailing newline (so answer will be 14 and not 13).

Comment: Use -m for chars, not -c which is for bytes

Comment: echo adds a newline unless you use the -n flag, however not all implementations of echo support the -n flag. use printf for a more consistent result

Comment: please note that using (admittedly cool) here-string solution suggested by @jacwah you end up counting one character more, because bash always adds a newline to the end of the string.

Answer (score 33):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ mystring="one two three four five"
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ echo "string length: ${#mystring}"
string length: 23
```

link
[Couting characters, words, lenght of the words and total lenght in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736856/bash-script-to-count-word-charcters-in-string)

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: This worked for me on Jenkinsfile, but without the # sign.
`echo "string length: ${mystring}"`

Comment: Using this I get an incorrect count. This happens when my string has colors and other format elements such as bold, background, etc.

Answer (score 17):

```
${#str_var}
```

where `str_var` is your string.

Answer (score 3):

you can use wc to count the number of characters in the file 
wc -m filename.txt.
Hope that help.

Comment: Not really. Example echo "ok" | wc -m -> 3

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil, echo -n

Comment: Yes, thanks. I ve noticed that echo always includes a new line at the end and that you can remove it with -n option.

Comment: echo can be inconsistent depending on your shell, printf is far more consistent